# API: Calling URL using curl in Python

Tags: python, json, api, url, curl

I'm trying to use a link shortening service in my python script, but their [API documentation](https://www.capsulink.com/docs/api) is in JSON (which calls URL using curl). I'm a beginner so I didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: check the `subprocess` module of python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the very first example of the documentation provided, you can simply use the `requests` module like so:

```
import requests

data = '{"username":"<Username or email>","password":"<Password>"}' #equal to: -d '{"url":"<Some URL>"}'

response = requests.get('https://www.capsulink.com/api/login', data=data)
```

Everything else can be build from that.

**Edit**

Requesting the shortened link using `requests`:

```
import requests

header = {"Api-Key": "<Some API key>"} #equal to: -H 'Api-Key: <Some API key>'

data = '{"url": "<Some URL>"}' #equal to: -d '{"url":"<Some URL>"}'

response = requests.get('https://www.capsulink.com/api/capsulate', headers=header, data=data)
```

Just replace `"<Some API key>"` with the API key you need and `"<Some URL>"` with the respective url you are interested in.

Comment: This is very helpful and on point! Can you please show how can I get the shortened link? (Probably the second example in the documentation). Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: @Lolee I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the very popular python library named requests. [Here](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/) is official documentation with examples.

```
>>> import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.json()
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python Request module (https://github.com/psf/requests/) to help you with the API query. It is easy and quick to implement.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Refer to the module definition here: https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/